# How can I upload large files by chunk, pieces?

Tags: uploading

I have got a little file sharing webpage. It's free to use it. I would like to upload files between 0mb and 1GB. I'm searching in Google since two days, but I can't find anything what I needed...

I can upload only 20-30mb now. I would like upload only 1 file at once. But it may be bigger than 500-600mb ... Can anyone help me?

Comment: To my understanding one option is if the browser supports [file api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) and the [blob object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob). This [stackoverflow question about upload large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646355/) has also some answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can circumvent upload and post limits if you start at the client side. A lot of Flash apps, JAVA apps and JS examples exist, if you google, like "multi upload chunk", things like that.

It depends on your preferences, here is a Javascript example:
http://creativejs.com/tutorials/advanced-uploading-techniques-part-1/

And a Flash one:
http://www.uploadify.com/download/

And a Java based one:
http://jupload.sourceforge.net/

The good thing with a method like this is that you can adjust to your limits on the server side and even display the upload progress.

Comment: Do you know any flash uploader for single file? I'm google it, but only show they with commercial license... I can't buy them... :-(

Comment: Yes, updated my answer. Enjoy.

Comment: Flash uploader gives me 2028 error. :-(

Comment: @initall creativejs not worked

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 methods that I believe will work for overcome this problem.

**Method 1) Edit the php.ini**

If the problem is that it seems that your web hosting does not support more than 30mb then it could be the fact that you just need to increase the maximum allowed amount in the php.ini file.

You can edit the php.ini and change the values to:

```
upload_max_filesize = 1001M
post_max_size = 1001M
```

You may also need to increase the [max_input_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php) as well.

**Method 2) Winrar is your friend**

Another solution to your problem is that you can split your files into smaller chunks and then extract them on the server using the File Manager assuming you have a control panel provided which allows for this. While there are lots of file splitters a personal favorite of mine is [**Rarsoft Winrar**](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm). Once you install WinRar you just right click the file you want to split, I've attached a image to display the usual settings you can use.

[Winrar Split Example http://www.bybe.net/downloads/winrar-split-example.jpg](http://www.bybe.net/downloads/winrar-split-example.jpg)

Comment: The problem is. If I edit the php.ini values thanI need a very strong server. I have got 2gb memory. If 3 people upload large file at the same time, than my system will die... I think... 

The archive... Yeah, I know it. I can upload my file in pieces, but the people don't want to do it... They want easy file share system... :-(